# ASP.NET spa.useReactDevelopmentServer(...) works fine, but setState does not work on it

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net

I have been looked for a solution for hours to get the react development server work. First I had a cors problem, which I had fixed yesterday. The problem now is small, but I want to fix it absolutely.

I have looked for a solution in some stackoverflow posts, but haven t found my solution in there, yet. If I take the line - "spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(..)" - out, everything works fine. But I want to use the ReactDevelopmentServer, which causes that useState does not re-render the ReactApp. Normally it would do it, but if I add the DevelopmentServer it does not.

```
using ToDoList.Domain.Service;
using ToDoList.Domain.Repository.Tasks;
using ToDoList.Domain.Repository;
// using ToDoList.Test.Mocks;
using ToDoList.Domain.Repository.Users;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using ToDoList.Domain.MsSql;
using ToDoList.Domain.Hasher;
using ToDoList.Domain.Tokens;
using ToDoList.Domain.Salt;
using System.Data.Common;
using ToDoList.Service.Middleware.Authorizations;
using ToDoList.Service.Middleware.Exceptions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var baseDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseDirectory))
{
    baseDirectory = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule?.FileName;

    if (baseDirectory == null)
    {
        baseDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

    }
    else
    {
        baseDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(baseDirectory);
    }
}

string connectionString = @"Trusted_Connection=True; server=DESKTOP-9ICM4BN\HISARSQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=master; User ID=DESKTOP-9ICM4BN\Nutzer;";

await using var connectionMaster = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

Mssql sql = new Mssql();

await sql.CreateDatabase(connectionMaster);

//Hier jetzt initial aufbauen.

connectionString = @"Trusted_Connection=True; server=DESKTOP-9ICM4BN\HISARSQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=tasks; User ID=DESKTOP-9ICM4BN\Nutzer;";

await using var connectionTasks = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

await sql.CreateInitial(connectionTasks);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
// builder.Services.AddHostedService<DeleteExpiredTokensBackgroundService>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<TaskService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<UserService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ISaltGenerator, SaltGenerator>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IHasher, Hasher>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITokenGenerator, TokenGenerator>();

// Lazy auch noch üben und anschauen. Kuckste mol!

// builder.Services.AddTransient<Lazy<UnitOfWork>>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<Func<SqlConnection, DbTransaction, TaskRepository>>((_) => (conn, trans) => new TaskRepository(conn, trans));
builder.Services.AddTransient<Func<SqlConnection, DbTransaction, UserRepository>>((_) => (conn, trans) => new UserRepository(conn, trans));
builder.Services.AddTransient<SqlConnection>((_) => new SqlConnection(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddScoped<UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<TokenAuthorization>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<CatchExceptionsMiddleware>();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot/build";
});

var app = builder.Build();

//Probier mal, ob du in die Middleware alle exceptions reinpacken kannst.
app.UseMiddleware<CatchExceptionsMiddleware>();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "wwwroot";

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDirectory ?? System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot"));
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});




app.Run();
```

This is my program.cs.

The following is the package.json in my wwwroot-folder:

```
{
  "name": "login",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/example-data": "^8.4.6",
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.105.3",
    "@fluentui/react-components": "^9.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.10",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18",
    "axios": "0.24.0",
    "node": "^19.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now follows my launchSettings of service-folder:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50501",
      "sslPort": 44330
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "service": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7021;http://localhost:5190",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

and finally my launch.json, because I use the debug mode:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
  
    {
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/App.js",
      "request": "launch",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "type": "node"
    },
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/service/bin/Debug/net6.0/service.dll",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/service",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Attach",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach"
    }
  ]
}
```

I looked in several Threads, but the problem they had wasn t the one which I have. I have not that much knowledge, because I am in the first year of an apprenticeship. Would be great if u could help me.